# How to track function in Flutter?

Tags: timer, dart, flutter

I have a habit to keep tracking how long my function is running, in `react native` I can use `console.time` with [react-native-console-time-polyfill](https://github.com/MaxGraey/react-native-console-time-polyfill)

```
myFunction(){
  console.time("Func Foo")
  //any logic here
  console.timeEnd("Func Foo")
}
```

how can I do that using Flutter?

Comment: [Stopwatch](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) maybe?

Comment: @pskink i'm not really sure about this, does it takes an effect of slowing the apps if i use it continuously?

Comment: continuously? what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, using it too much for most of my function

Comment: @flix How would using `Stopwatch` be different from using `console.time` in that regard?

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't know about that, because i just touch `Flutter` a couple days ago, i just think the `Stopwatch` created not for debugging purpose

Comment: `"i just think the Stopwatch created not for debugging purpose"` - see for example how [VerboseLogger](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/base/logger.dart#L337) uses `Stopwatch`

Comment: @pskink So i don't need to worry about `Stopwatch` then, but how do you find if VerboseLogger using `stopwatch` btw?

Comment: how? by using [grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) command on my installed `flutter` distribution

Comment: @flix please let me know if you have any issues in the solution provided below. Thanks

Comment: @flix Why does it need to be created specifically for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try this..

```
void main() async {
  var dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();

  await someExecution(); // call your function here.

  var dateTimeAfterExecution = DateTime.now();

  var difference = dateTimeAfterExecution.difference(dateTimeNow);
  print(difference.inMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
myFunction(){
  var oldTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  //any logic here

  // total time taken to run the logic would be
  print("time = ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - oldTime} ms");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL.

You can get all the information for debugging in the flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging

It will help you.

Comment: i think you're misunderstanding

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.